# Div Not Displaying On Click With JQuery (CSS - Block/None)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like it so when I click on a Bootstrap Glyphicon a div is displayed.
I currently have this HTML (simplified):

```
<span id="headerdisplaybuttonsxs" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"> </span>
<div id="headerrightside" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"> text... </div>
```

Then this JS:

```
$('#headerdisplaybuttonsxs').click(function()) {
    $('#headerrightside').css("display", "block");
});
```

So I would basically like `#headerrightside` to display on the clicking of `#headerdisplaybuttonsxs`. Problem is I can't get that to work.

**`#headerdisplaybuttonsxs` Has a CSS property of `display:none`.**

I have tried `$('#headerrightside').show()` but that does not seem to work. How could I get this to work? Thank You!!

Comment: i think you you have a typo in the code --  .click(function() { ... });

Comment: Typo yep, an extra `)`. Thank you so much! Still new to JS, I am a PHP person... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a typo on the click event function with an extra ).

```js
$('#headerdisplaybuttonsxs').click(function() {
    $('#headerrightside').css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
#headerrightside {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="headerdisplaybuttonsxs" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger">Icon</span>
<div id="headerrightside" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"> text... </div>
```